# Android Shared Preference TinyDB putListObject function

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to save an object list to the Shared Preferences using TinyDB's `putListObject` function, but I'm getting a `Wrong 2nd argument type` error. I can use the `putObject` function just fine, the error only appears when I use the `putListObject` function.

---

Player Class:

```
public class Player {

    private String name = "";
    private int score = 0;

    public Player(String name, int score) {
        this.name = name;
        this.score = score;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public void setScore(int score) {
        this.score = score;
    }
}
```

putListObject function:

```
 public void putListObject(String key, ArrayList<Object> objArray){
        checkForNullKey(key);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        ArrayList<String> objStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(Object obj : objArray){
            objStrings.add(gson.toJson(obj));
        }
        putListString(key, objStrings);
    }
```

How I used the function:

```
ArrayList<Player> playerList = new ArrayList<Player>();

TinyDB tinydb = new TinyDB(this);
tinydb.putListObject("players", playerList);
```

The error I got:

> putListObject (String java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Object>) in TinyDB
>   cannot be applied to (String
>   java.util.ArrayList<com.example.package.Player>)

---

Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

kcochibili Developer of TinyDB answered this on github.
He says, you must cast your custom objects to object before trigger putListObject.

A sample for putting Custom Object ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();
ArrayList<Object> playerObjects = new ArrayList<Object>();

for(Player a : players){
    playerObjects.add((Object)a);
}

TinyDB tinydb = new TinyDB(this);
tinydb.putListObject("players", playerObjects);
```

Also when you want to get values from DB it will give ArrayList< Object >. So you may want to cast them back to your custom object.

A sample for this:

```
TinyDB tinydb = new TinyDB(this);
ArrayList<Object> playerObjects = tinydb.getListObject("players", Player.class);
ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();

for(Object objs : playerObjects){
    players.add((Player)objs);
}
```

You can use all custom objects by casting.
The other way i prefer is, adding get and put methods for all custom objects to TinyDB Class.
For example :

```
public void putListPlayer(String key, ArrayList<Player> playerList){
    checkForNullKey(key);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    ArrayList<String> objStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(Player player: playerList){
        objStrings.add(gson.toJson(player));
    }
    putListString(key, objStrings);
}

//No need Class<?> mClass parameter. Because we know it is Player!
public ArrayList<Player> getListPlayer(String key){
    Gson gson = new Gson(); 

    ArrayList<String> objStrings = getListString(key);
    ArrayList<Player> playerList =  new ArrayList<Player>();

    for(String jObjString : objStrings){
        Player player  = gson.fromJson(jObjString,  Player.class);
        playerList.add(player);
    }
    return playerList;
}
```

Comment: Faith K, I know "thank yous" are passé and frowned upon, but you saved me hours of work and I wanted to express more appreciation than just a simple up-vote!

A full working example would, however, go a long way in explaining it for others.

Comment: What will happen if I call `putListPlayer` using the same key multiple times? Will it keep updating the value at that key or will it throw an error?

Comment: Hii @Faith K Thanks. I have used your second way for my custom array list storage.

Comment: @RavishJha calling ``putListPlayer`` again. or any TinyDB function will update the value that was last saved with the specified key.

Answer (score 7):

Although any instance of `Player` is an `Object`, an `ArrayList` of Players is not the same as an `ArrayList` of Objects. Change your method signature to :

```
putListObject(String key, ArrayList<Player> objArray)
```

and for loop to:

```
for(Player player : objArray){
   objStrings.add(gson.toJson(player));
}
```